# Android AdMob - Requesting Consent from European Users

Tags: android, admob, gdprconsentform

I implemented **EU User Consent Policy** with **Android** + **AdMob** according to [this article](https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/android/quick-start).

**The Problem**: `UserMessagingPlatform` always failed on `onConsentInfoUpdateFailure` either on real device (with HashedId) or on simulators.

**The error**: *Invalid response from server: Failed to read publisher's account configuration; try again later.*

I have debug settings enabled:

```
ConsentDebugSettings debugSettings = new ConsentDebugSettings.Builder(activity)
        .setDebugGeography(ConsentDebugSettings.DebugGeography.DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA)
        //.addTestDeviceHashedId("CC3EBF623628DAA1E3AD2124AE690FBD")
        .build();

ConsentRequestParameters params = new ConsentRequestParameters.Builder()
        .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false)
        .setConsentDebugSettings(debugSettings)
        .build();
```

Please let me know why it fails? May be I should consider using [Legacy version](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent) instead?

Comment: is correct publisher id provided? e.g. String[] publisherIds = {"pub-0123456789012345"};

Comment: I'm trying to use a new version - https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/android/quick-start (not LEGACY). New version doesn't have `publisherIds` parameter anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set up a Funding Choices account as described here https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/9770970

Comment: But it needs special request to have an account, great! Now I have the reason to just remove this instead.

Answer (score 6):

I have just had this response after setting up for the first time. I solved it by changing some settings in Admob itself.

[Google Admob](https://admob.google.com/home/) -> Privacy & messaging -> GDPR (card)

Create a message that actually gets displayed to the user (consent/do not consent/manage options etc.), I believe this is what is not actually found when this error appears. There are a number of toggle buttons to determine which message gets displayed (personalised ads/basic ads/etc.).

There is also the ability to age restrict ads which will be useful if you're releasing your app for children.

Comment: *There is also the ability to age restrict ads which will be useful if you're releasing your app for children.* I would like to know where it is.

Comment: I "believe" it may have been the 'Admob->Blocking Controls->Ad content rating' section of your general admob account and also the 'Admob->Blocking Controls->Sensitive categories' section.