# Android UMP - Request consent always fails

Tags: android, admob, google-ad-manager, gdprconsentform

I implemented consent request using UMP according to this [guide](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/ump/android/quick-start).

I use real device to check the implementation:

```kotlin
    fun initialize(activity: Activity) {
        val params = ConsentRequestParameters.Builder()

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            val debugSettings = ConsentDebugSettings.Builder(context)
                .setDebugGeography(ConsentDebugSettings.DebugGeography.DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA)
                .addTestDeviceHashedId("E608A703339C5546343D0D3A2AC00FB0")
                .build()
            params.setConsentDebugSettings(debugSettings)
        }

        consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
                activity,
                params.build(),
                {
                    // Proceed with result
                },
                { log.debug("error during consent request $it") }
        )
    }
```

Each time this results in error:
`W/UserMessagingPlatform: Invalid response from server: Failed to read publisher's account configuration; try again later.`

Things I've already checked:

- App ID (from AdManager) in Manifest is correct.
- There are no additional parameters in request, everything as described in guide.
- Referred to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65690413/android-admob-requesting-consent-from-european-users), we have Funding Choices account. And right now it is in transition, as mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/10589261).
- Account is active and not [under verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69793748/usermessagingplatform-invalid-response-from-server).

Any ideas why it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message, specific to app and regulation zone was missing.
Inside ad managing service (AdManager, AdMob, etc), in **Privacy & messaging** section. There should be specific message added for zone (e.g. GDPR). It is required step to make UMP work.

[image]