# App closes on start while using ti.admob module

Tags: ios, admob, titanium

I'm trying to integrate the `ti.admob` module in my Titanium app to use it with iOS.

The problem that I am having is that if I simply include the module in the `tiapp.xml` file the app stops working. It tries to open but then closes alone without even showing the splash screens.

I have tried several versions of the module; Several of `3.x.x`, `4.0.0`, and `4.8.0`, and none worked.

How can I get the module to work or what am I missing that is causing my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add keys to the tiapp.xml. For that have a look at the official docs at https://github.com/tidev/ti.admob/blob/master/apidoc/Admob.yml#L43 and also this issue https://github.com/tidev/ti.admob/issues/306 that talks about `crashes on launch` with some information too (there is a Manuel in the thread, not sure if that is already you  )

about the different versions:

the latest should be the best here since it is using a newer version of the ad framework. BUT it includes some adaptars that might not be needed. Be sure to read some infos in the PR (https://github.com/tidev/ti.admob/pull/166).

Comment: Hi, thanks. With your help and from GitHub I managed to make it to worke. I'm havgin now an other problem. I have set all my Id's using the onse I get from google admob page, but I allways get the message "Failed to read publisher's account configuration; try again later.". Can you hel me with that?

Comment: no, not using it. But there are other posts with that error you can look at. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65690413/android-admob-requesting-consent-from-european-users